# Does the concept of thinking/learning of something better when you have "skin in the game" originate with Taleb?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy

I recently read the [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_in_the_Game_(book)) by Taleb in which he writes that having skin in the game with respect to something allows one to have insights about it which one wouldn't (easily?) otherwise.
Since Taleb rarely cites anything in his works I have the following question:
Is there any direct close predecessor to this concept?

Comment: No. It is a repackaged old platitude that people are best motivated by what affects them personally:"*When everyone has a distinct interest, men will not complain of one another, and they will make more progress, because every one will be attending to his own business*", Aristotle, Politics. Psychologists call it self-interest bias. Extra "insights" come from paying more attention to it, and there is extra willingness to act. It has been used as an argument for free markets and private property, and already Marx explicitly argued against it from his collectivist idea about "human nature".

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. It seems that very little is new in Taleb's writings

Comment: He has an uncanny ability to point out the obvious, which is nonetheless ignored or overlooked, and present it in a witty charismatic style with compelling examples. The downside is that the morals he draws from his examples are highly context dependent, but there is little analysis of this dependence in his writings despite the generalistic language.

Comment: @GEP To be fair, very little is new in anyone's writings

Comment: @b a  Not really , it depends on how you define it